# Pantheon-files crash

Tags: pantheon-files

Yesterday I start work and take my laptop to office. In home I have automount NFS drive. Now in my office I cannot start Pantheon-files - "Window is not Responding..." It works when I run from terminal:

```
io.elementary.files
```

Regards Przemek

Comment: It is odd that it works from the commandline but not from the dock (I assume that is how you are trying to start it unsuccessfully). You could use system-monitor or htop to check whether Files is running in a loop and become unresponsive.  The NFS mount should not matter.  You could try changing the Files setting `io.elementary.files.preferences.restore-tabs` to see whether it helps.  Make sure all existing Files processes are killed.  If there is one that has hung it may prevent anymore being started.

Comment: Hi, thank for Your answer. When I try today it won't start from command line either.
`$ io.elementary.files                                                                                                                                                                          
** Message: 14:03:16.758: Application.vala:50: Report any issues/bugs you might find to https://github.com/elementary/files/issues
[1]    19554 killed     io.elementary.files`

Comment: `$ io.elementary.files.preferences.restore-tabs                                                                                                                                        
zsh: command not found: io.elementary.files.preferences.restore-tabs`

Comment: To change the `io.elementary.files.preferences.restore-tabs` setting to "off", use the command `gsettings set io.elementary.files.preferences restore-tabs false`.   Or you could install "DConf Editor" from the appcenter if you prefer to use a GUI.

Comment: The error message from the command line suggests that the Files process was killed by the system rather than crashed.  Not obvious why that should be.  Could you give more info about the system you are running it on as `zsh` is not the default elementary shell.

Comment: Hi, I use last Elementary release on Dell Inspiron laptop. I install gthumb and it start very slow and sometimes crashed. I noticed that I have random system freezes and only mouse works then.

Comment: Hi, Jeremy Wootten. Thanks to that command You give me above now Files and gThumb start fast but still have some freezes on Google-Chrome.

Comment: There have been a number of reports of random system freezes - e.g. https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/803 - I have occasionally experienced it myself.  However, I do not think the reason has been traced yet.  Unlikely to be due to Files.

Comment: Hi, I don't know what I mess but now after some upgrade I have very slow start of wingpanel and desktop widgets (I have folder view and yellow sticky notes). I see desktop and plank but I have to wait about 2 min to wingpanel and widgets turn on.

Comment: Sounds like one of the indicators is taking a long time to initialize and maybe eventually timing out.  Ideally that should not slow the panel appearing but I would need to check the code to see if the indicators are initialized asynchronously.  It is probably worth raising an issue about at https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/issues

Comment: You can maybe get some info by killing `wingpanel` (you will need to do it twice in a row to stop it automatically restarting). Restart it in a terminal with `G_MESSAGES_DEBUG=all wingpanel`.  Note what messages are shown while the wingpanel is waiting to appear and any immediately after it appears (this will also show messages from all the indicators).  Wingpanel will close if you close the terminal so you will need to log out and back in afterwards.  You can always close the session with the `<Ctrl><Alt><Del>` shortcut.

Comment: Use "Gnome System Monitor" from AppCenter to kill the process unless you know how to do it from the commandline).